# Docker: /bin/sh: 1: /tmp/provision.sh: not found

Tags: docker, heroku, splash-screen

I'm trying to deploy the latest scrapinghub/splash

I am using git-bash on win10. I forked the repo to https://github.com/kc1/splash/blob/master

and I have been trying to follow [Using docker, scrapy splash on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046045/using-docker-scrapy-splash-on-heroku/47414276#47414276) to modify the docker file

to https://github.com/kc1/splash/blob/master/Dockerfile

but when I run:

```
$ heroku container:push web --app splash1
=== Building web (E:\ENVS\r3\splash1\Dockerfile)
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.333MB
Step 1/11 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 2a697363a870
Step 2/11 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d65460bd23ae
Step 3/11 : ENV PATH="/opt/qt59/5.9.1/gcc_64/bin:${PATH}"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f8ad62632743
Step 4/11 : ADD dockerfiles/splash/provision.sh /tmp/provision.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5fc632a5001f
Step 5/11 : ADD dockerfiles/splash/qt-installer-noninteractive.qs /tmp/script.qs
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 174d06a23d89
Step 6/11 : RUN /tmp/provision.sh     prepare_install     install_deps     install_qtwebkit_deps     install_official_qt     install_qtwebkit     install_pyqt5     install_python_deps
    install_flash     install_msfonts     install_extra_fonts     remove_builddeps     remove_extra &&     rm /tmp/provision.sh
 ---> Running in 45dd729ec969
/bin/sh: 1: /tmp/provision.sh: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c /tmp/provision.sh     prepare_install     install_deps     install_qtwebkit_deps     install_official_qt     install_qtwebkit     install_pyqt5     install_pyth
on_deps     install_flash     install_msfonts     install_extra_fonts     remove_builddeps     remove_extra &&     rm /tmp/provision.sh' returned a non-zero code: 127
 !    Error: docker build exited with Error: 127
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you are trying to launch a Linux shell command from Windows...

Comment: Check your script for Windows linefeeds. You need Linux style linefeeds for shell scripts.

Comment: @BMitch I'm brand new to docker. What script do you mean? The Dockerfile?

Comment: @user61629 the provision.sh script. Though if you have this issue with one script, you likely need to check the entire repo that you've cloned.

Comment: Thanks , I recloned using git clone --config core.eol=lf <repository> and was able to solve this error.